# Building a NFT marketplace with Thirdweb's SDK and Frontend with React JS

Tags: reactjs

Can someone tell me the disadvantages and limits of using Thirdweb's SDK to build a NFT marketplace?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Happy to help here - I'm Devin with thirdweb btw.

As far as our marketplace contract, you can list any erc721/1155 for direct or auction sales. In order to set up a full-fledged marketplace, you'll want to build out a front end.

With that in mind, we created a starter template you can clone and build of off here: https://portal.thirdweb.com/templates/marketplace

Hope this helps and feel free to drop us any other questions.